# How can I acess a metod from an object inside a class in python 2.6?

Tags: python, class

In my code I have a class that contain a lot of functions and a pair of classes (subclass I think). The main problem is that I want the subclasses to call an object, defined in the function **init** and I don't know ho to referencing it

The main issue in code:

```
class principal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = object()
...

...
    class secondary(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            a.proceed() # problem !!!
```

I've tried to call a like principal.a.proceed() but the Traceback tells me:
    AttributeError: class principal has no attribute 'a'

how can I solve this. It appear that it is something easy to solve, but I can't see it.

Comment: For lots of reasons (including that Python folk expect it), consider "class Principal(object)".... capital name on the class, and derive from 'object'

Comment: @Jubeor: Are you coming from a Java-background? Of so, note that nested classes in Python are not automatically bound to an instance of the surrounding class, like they are in Java. You have to pass an instance explicitly in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Java, there will not be a new `principal.secondary` class for each instance of `principal`. When you declare a class inside another class (a classeption :P) in Python it only means that the inside class will be accessed as a class attribute of the outside class and *nothing* more. So, there is no outside instance of `principal` to be accessed from the `principal.secondary` methods.

Indeed, you want to do something meaningless in Python. I would suggest you  do whatever you are trying to do by some other way. For example, you can get an instance of `principal` and pass it as parameter for the constructor of `principal.secondary`:

```
p = principal()
s = principal.secondary(p)
```

Also, note that `principal.secondary` is not a subclass of `principal` but only a class inside a class. "Subclasses" are classes that extends/inherits from another one. So, `principal.secondary` is a subclass of `threading.Thread`, not from principal.

Finally, two little off-topic suggestions: always make your classes extend `object` if it does not extend any other class and follow the [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) by starting the name of your classes by an uppercase letter:

```
class Principal(object):
    ...
```

**EDIT**: If you *really* want to have a class bound to an instance like in Java (and I doubt you want),there is a way to emulate it. Create a function that receives an object as parameter, declare and return the class:

```
def generateSecondary(outerObject):
    class Secondary(object):
        def __init__(self):
            outerObject.proceed()
    return Secondary
```

The `outerObject` parameter will be bound to the class declared inside the function.

Now, declare your `Principal` class. Call the `generateSecondary()` function in the `__init__` method of `Principal` passing the initializing object as parameter and setting it to an attribute of the initializing object:

```
class Principal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = "an attribute of %s" % self
        self.Secondary = generateSecondary(self)

    def proceed(self):
        print self.attribute
```

The result is:

```
>>> principal = Principal()
>>> secondary = principal.Secondary()
an attribute of <classeption.Principal object at 0x2e3970>
>>> secondary
<classeption.Secondary object at 0x2e3a10>
```

It is possible because Python classes are first-class objects that can be bound to closures (in the traditional sense of "closure"). I do not recommend to use such code but there is a way to do what you *asked* - which may not be what you *need*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate a principal object in the `__init__` for `secondary`

```
p = principal()
```

and then reference the a object

```
pa = p.a()
pa.proceed()
```

Note that my variables names are horrendous

Note too that you're not subclassing `principal`, you're subclassing `threading.Thread`.  Indenting isn't enough, you have to include the superclass in the class definition