# Accessing parent class variable from an inner class?

Tags: python, inner-classes, locust

I am working with locust and I am working in mimicking the behavior of a user. However I am getting trouble accessing the parent class variable. Any idea how I can pass it?

```
class User(TaskSet):
  some_user = ''

  def on_start(self):
    self.get_user()

  def get_user(self):
    some_user = self.client.get...#gets user

  @task
  class UpdatingUser(TaskSet):
    def updating(self):
      path = "/posts/" + User.some_user
```

By the time I get to User.some_user I never have the user.

Comment: If you haven't called `get_user()`, why would `some_user` have been set? The subclass init method needs to call the super class's init method, if that is where you are setting it.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840270/python-how-to-get-outer-class-variables-from-inner-static-class) will probably answer yours.

Comment: get_user gets called in the on_start functions of the User class. That's not the point of the question. @NathanielFord

Comment: Any chance you're coming from Java? Python inner classes aren't scoped (and static vs non-static) like Java's.

Comment: hahah yep. @DavidEhrmann Are there other ways to access it?

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided all of the code, but the problem may be that `get_user()` is setting `some_user` as an *instance attribute* somewhere, as in `self.some_user = foo`.

This will only set `some_user` for that specific instance of `User` however (so for Bob, Lisa, Beto, User53, etc.), but not for the `User` class itself.  When accessing `some_user` with `self`, as in `self.some_user`, you set it for the specific instance that's executing those statements, not the class. In `updating()` you're accessing the *class attribute* `User.some_user`, not a specific instance attribute like `usr53.some_user`. In order to update the class attribute, invariant by default for all instances of `User`, you ought to be setting it with `User.some_user = foo` in `get_user()`.

Right now in `path = "/posts/" + User.some_user`, it's trying to access the class attribute which may never have been set. Because nested classes like `UpdatingUser` can't access the instances of the nesting class (`User`) that they're called from, `UpdatingUser` won't be able to access any `some_user` set with `self` or any other instance attributes of `User`. So the solution would be to have `get_user()` set the class attribute instead of the instance attribute as described in the previous paragraph.

Comment: I updated the code. Interesting so a inner class has not access to the parent class variables? I know the way locust starts the class is by running on_start first and that's where I set the variable. But I wasn't sure how to access it once it s ran.

Comment: @Beto, It does have access to the parent's class variables (in my answer I said attributes instead of variables), but not its instance variables. In the code you posted you're neither setting some_user as a class variable nor an instance variable, but just a variable local in scope to the get_user function. Remember from my answer, setting self.some_user sets an instance variable, setting User.some_user sets the class variable persistent through all instances. When you set some_user outside of any methods like you did on line 2, it's automatically a class variable as if you did User.some_user.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late but, if anyone has this issue, the [TaskSet](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#taskset-class) has a `parent` property, which can be used to access the parent's instance variables. The following is what I used for a basic one-time login:

```
class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.token = self.login()
        self.headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token}

    def login(self):
        with self.client.post("/login", catch_response = True) as response:
            return response.json()['token']

    @task
    class UserTask1(TaskSet):
        @task
        def get_data(self):
            self.client.get("/data", headers = self.parent.headers)

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehaviour
```